# SendMessage as IPC?

Tags: c++, winapi

The following code sets some text to an open notepad window. My question is how does it work safely?

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
      HWND hwnd = FindWindow(_T("Notepad"),_T("Untitled - Notepad"));
      if(hwnd!=NULL)
      {
         wchar_t* pString = L"hi";
         HWND hwndEdit = FindWindowEx(hwnd,NULL,_T("Edit"),NULL);
         SendMessage(hwndEdit,WM_SETTEXT,0,(LPARAM)pString);
      }
       return 0;
```

}

The pointer "pString" exists in the virtual memory of the current process space, which might not be valid memory address in the context of notepad.exe.But strangely it does set the text correctly , which means not only the pointer is valid in the notepad.exe context but it points to the correct string also. How is this happening ?

Does that mean we can use SendMessage effectively as an IPC mechanism ?

Comment: SendMessage was in fact likely for IPC at one point, until dumb hackers got a hold of it to destroy operating systems and then they changed it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The system automatically marshals data from one process to another for certain messages - `WM_SETTEXT` is one of the messages that gets this special treatment.

You could certainly use it as an IPC mechanism for two-way data transfer (send using `WM_SETTEXT` and receive with `WM_GETTEXT`) if you really wanted to, but I doubt it would be that efficient. And there is already a message especially designed for IPC - `WM_COPYDATA`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was going through this link [link]](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10497/A-tool-to-order-the-window-buttons-in-your-taskbar). Here author has done some memory related handling for using SendMessage(). Is it perhaps because here we are using SendMessage () to fill some value in a local pointer varable.?? or is it really dependent on which message Windows handles marshaling of and which it does not?

Comment: `TB_GETBUTTON` is not one of the messages that Windows marshals cross-process, which is why that article uses the shenanigans it does. In general I think you could say that none of the common control messages would be marshalled like this, whereas User messages often are. I'm not sure if there's a definitive list somewhere or not.

Answer (score 0):

> we can use SendMessage

Yes!

> effectively

No

Setting text of window is processing by OS. Windows automatically marshals data in this case.